# Mask is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]
[image]

I have a inputbox with mask, but the inputs are not allowed by hardware keyboard, instead they have a touch-screen `keyboard()` function only that inserts the characters in that field.

But when `keyboard()` inserts the inputs in the input field it fails to generate the mask effects.

How to make the mask also work when `keyboard()` is used?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function keyboard(input) {
  if (input==='BACKSPACE') {
    tvalue = '';
  } else if(input ==='QUOTE') {
    tvalue = tvalue + "'";
  } else if(input ==='SPACE') {
    tvalue = tvalue + " ";
  } else {
    tvalue = tvalue + input;
  }    
  $('#' + tinput).val(tvalue);
  console.log(">>> Keyboard: ", input);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#rrn").mask('99.99.99-999.99');

//  $(document).bind('contextmenu', function()  {
//    console.log('Touch screen, has no right click.');
//    return false;
//  });
//  
//  $(document).mousedown( function() {
//    return false; 
//  });

});
</script>


<div>
  <input type="text" name="rrn" id="rrn" style="position: absolute; left: 519px; top: 195px; width: 366px; height: 42px;border:none;" autocomplete="off"  onclick="inputselected(this, event);"/>    
  <img src="images/nl/keyboard.png"  border="0" usemap="#map_logo_new" id="spmain_new" />
  <map name="map_logo_new">
  <area shape="rect" coords="825,19,910,74" href="#" onclick="keyboard(0);">
  <area shape="rect" coords="22,83,107,138" href="#" onclick="keyboard('A');">  
   </map>    
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are programmatically setting the value of the input, which does not cause any events to trigger. In order to force the mask to be applied, you need to trigger an event yourself (after calling `.val()`).

Try changing to this:

```
  $('#' + tinput).val(tvalue).trigger('input');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82zwh3g3/)

---

This is for the jQuery Masked Input Plugin from Josh Bush at digitalbush.com.

- http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
- https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput

---

At this time the latest version of this libary is v1.4. For an earlier version of the library you may have to try the `'click'` event.

Comment: Not working just tried the .change() but still same, mask not working when keyboard() function is used.

Comment: .click() also not working, it only inputing one value and then still mask effects are not working

Comment: @YumYumYum - I'm trying to look at the source code to see what to do. If you want to try another: `$('#' + tinput).val(tvalue).trigger('keydown');`

Comment: .trigger() also failed, same no luck with .click(), .change(), .trigger() yet.

Comment: @YumYumYum - How about `.trigger('input')`?

Comment: After looking at the source, `'input'` and `'paste'` are the two events that would work.